# Issue in Rxjs and webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, rxjs, yarnpkg, falcor

In my project, I am using [falcor](https://netflix.github.io/falcor) which happen to have Rxjs as a dependency which has a [known problem with webpack](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor#important-note-for-webpack-users).
So far after following what the previous link says everything works fine.
Alongside I am using [concurrently](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/concurrently) as a DevDependency, which has Rxjs as a dependency but with a newer version then falcor, when I compile my scripts with webpack I get an error in the browser:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
>       at inherits.inherits.Rx.internals.inherits

I solved the problem by installing Rx as a dependency in my project with the version used by falcor.

Here I am asking is there any solution with either yarn or npm to solve the problem without adding Rx as a dependency.

Comment: Where is the error thrown?  From your project, the falcor dependency, elsewhere?  Looks like concurrently is a CLI tool, so wouldn't be built into your project, no?

Comment: Also, FYI there is a fork of the Netflix falcor client repo that uses RxJS 5 as a peer dependency; could solve the problem if it's an issue w/ competing or old versions of RxJS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@graphistry/falcor

Comment: The error is thrown in the browser console after been bundled successfully with webapck.

Comment: The reason I am asking this question is not precisely for this case but in the future when I face problems like this how it can be solved.